# Converting lonlat to xyz and vice versa

Tags: math, three.js

I'm using this code to translate lonlat to x,y,z but can't figure out how to do the opposite.

```
var phi = (this.lat)*Math.PI/180;
var theta = (this.lon-180)*Math.PI/180;

x = -(this.R) * Math.cos(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
y = -(this.R) * Math.sin(phi);
z = (this.R) * Math.cos(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
```

Now converting from x,y,z to lonlat

```
lat = THREE.Math.radToDeg(Math.asin(rotation.y / this.R));
lon = THREE.Math.radToDeg(Math.atan2(rotation.z, rotation.x));
```

But this does not work properly, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you arent converting from xyz to lon lat, you are trying to do something with euler angles:

try something like this

```
lon = Math.atan2( x , z ); //horizontal angle, just two components
lon = Math.atan2( Math.sqrt(x*x,z*z) , y ); //vertical angle, length of the diagonal between xz components and y component
```

Comment: I used this to translate rotation into xyz coordinates and then used my previous formula to get lonlat

`var xyz = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
this.camera.getWorldDirection(xyz);`

But thanks for help!